# Image registration (aligning one image to match another)

Tags: javascript, image-processing, alignment, photoshop-script

Currently I have an image that needs to be manipulated so it matches the same scale, position, and rotation as a template.

[image: image alignment]

The grey rectangle with a circle in the middle is the template.
The orange rectangle and circle represents the user's input. It needs to be rotated, scaled and aligned to it matches the grey one.  I'm currently stumped on how to proceed. I've no code other than the following.

```
function align_image()
{
 // clever transform alignment code here
}
```

Bad dog, no biscuit!

The process at of aligning the images would normally be done manual input and judged by eye. I'm hoping to automate this step and align the image to its respective size and position but leaving the comfort and safety of Photoshop DOM I'm not sure how to proceed or even if this is a trivial matter or one left best alone. The project is web based currently using javascript and three.js

So if anyone can give me some pointers I'd appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't code javascript so I can only talk about the algorithm. Generally best tool for registration is to use feature matching methods (using sift, surf,...) but your image is not the kind that have strong features. Now if you're always dealing with rectangles and circles in your images, find the "edges" of the rectangle with **Hough Transform**, compute the angle of those edges (lines) then rotate the image with that angle in the opposite direction.

Then with the help of **Hough Circle Detector**, find the center of the circles in the middle of the images, calculate the distance between them, and move the target rectangle to the source's circle position. After the movement by comparing the radius of the circles, you can resize the target image to make it like the source rectangle.

All of these are conveniently doable with Opencv.